# React setState to update field of a nested Object

Tags: react-native, setstate, spread

I am working on my App in React Native, and I was using to use the spread operator to keep the state of this object coming from backend, the problem is that I cannot update the field of a nested object inside this big object.

Example:

```
{
  foo: "bar",
  lee: {
     fee: "yoo"
  }
}
```

using React setState, how can I access the fee key of the lee object?
I tried with `setState(...object, object.lee.fee: value)` but this seems not working.

Any good tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
var someProperty = {...this.state.someProperty}
someProperty.lee = {fee : value};
this.setState({someProperty})
```

Comment: It works, I didn't know that setState cannot handle nested objects :/